# Create a segment in x86 protected mode

Tags: x86, memory-segmentation

In x86 architecture if i use protected mode and segmented memory model, i can use segment.
My doubt is the following: is there a method to create, set or specify a segment (its limit and other properties) or it is managed automatically?

Thanks

Comment: As I understand it, you have to create an entry in the LDT or GDT.  Setting a 16bit segment register in 32bit mode just gives the CPU a selector to load the full info from a descriptor in the Global Descriptor Table.  Not posting this as an answer because it's not at all complete.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links, esp. http://wiki.osdev.org/, which has [a page on segmentation](http://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation#Protected_Mode).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer.
Maybe you're right...i need to create an entry in GDT.

Comment: You create a global descriptor table that contains the size and offset of the GDT table itself. Each GDT entry describes the segment descriptors. A good tutorial is in this [document](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/lectures/opsys/10_11/lectures/os-dev.pdf) . Of interest is Section 4.2 onwar. The concept of segmentation in real mode and protected mode is different.